# Switched from PHP version 4 to version 5.3 - code not working anymore

Tags: php

I recently swithced php version from 4 to 5.3. I now how some code that is not working anymore. I have a PHP script that fetches data from a form into a new form, when a user clicks a link.

First it recognizes the user/account and after that it finds the form data.

This is the code for the account data:

```
$account_info = ft_get_account_info($_SESSION["ft"]["account"]["account_id"]);
$emailadresse = ($account_info['email']);
$accountid = ($account_info['account_id']);
$firstname =($account_info['first_name']);
$lastname =($account_info['last_name']);
```

....
....

This works, and i can display the data through for example a:

```
<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>
```

I then have this code in order to fetch and display the form data:

```
$submission_info = ft_get_submission_info($form_id, $submission_id);
$submission_id = ($submission_info['submission_id']);
$partname = ($submission_info['partname']);
$ponumber = ($submission_info['ponumber']);
....
....
<?php echo $_POST['partname']; ?>
```

This is not working anymore in version 5.3 of PHP.

Can anyone please tell what i need to re-write this code into, in order for it to work...????

Thanks in advance!

In addition to the comments i have this code for the ft_get_account_info:

```
$_SESSION["ft"]["account"]  = ft_get_account_info($account_info["account_id"]);
```

And this for the ft_get_submission_info:

```
/**
* Returns all information about a submission. N.B. Would have been nice to have made this just a
 * wrapper for ft_get_submission_info, but that function contains hooks. Need to revise all core
 * code to allow external calls to optionally avoid any hook calls.
 *
 * @param integer $form_id
 * @param integer $submission_id
 */
function ft_api_get_submission($form_id, $submission_id)
{
  global $g_table_prefix, $g_api_debug;
  // confirm the form is valid
  if (!ft_check_form_exists($form_id))
  {
    if ($g_api_debug)
    {
      $page_vars = array("message_type" => "error", "error_code" => 405, "error_type" => "user");
      ft_display_page("../../global/smarty/messages.tpl", $page_vars);
      exit;
    }
    else
      return array(false, 405);
  }
  if (!is_numeric($submission_id))
  {
    if ($g_api_debug)
    {
      $page_vars = array("message_type" => "error", "error_code" => 406, "error_type" => "user");
      ft_display_page("../../global/smarty/messages.tpl", $page_vars);
      exit;
    }
    else
      return array(false, 406);
  }
  // get the form submission info
  $submission_info = mysql_query("
     SELECT *
     FROM   {$g_table_prefix}form_{$form_id}
     WHERE  submission_id = $submission_id
              ");
  $submission = mysql_fetch_assoc($submission_info);
  return $submission;
}
```

Nothing on the error reporting.

Comment: What does the "ft_get_submission_info" function do? everything else looks like perfectly acceptable code

Comment: Does your errorlog contain any valuable information? Perhaps any deprecated functions or things like that?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: Do not forget to switch to mysqli/pdo as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated!

Comment: +1 for switching to PHP 5 finally :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your specific issue is, but I figure that if you use all the tools available to you for debugging, you'll be able to find your issue easily.

For development, you should always up your [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) level to `E_ALL ^ E_STRICT`. You can find this setting in your php.ini file. `E_STRICT` specifically will help identify interoperability and compatibility issues, and is not included in `E_ALL` until PHP 5.4, [according to the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).

You may also want to use Netbeans and XDebug, which should allow you to step through your code line by line, which will simplify debugging immensely. There is a guide for setting up these tools here: [Debugging PHP Source Code in the NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html)